# octave - parsing non-delimited text with textscan

Tags: octave

I have a large set of data in a file. Each line has the format:

1 character, integer, optional text, optional "#"

There are no whitespaces, commas, etc. Can I use textscan to delimit these fields.

An example

w0319

a29cde

b54863fgh

c4ijk#

b076mno

a7356pqr

d78#

b678

h765677stuvwx

Thank you

Comment: maybe, but it's probably easier to use `fileread` to read the file as a string, and then `strsplit` to separate lines, and take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

No need for textscan. Something along the following lines will give you a good result and more control, and a nice struct array at the end of it.

```matlab
% Read file and split into lines as a cell array
S = fileread('myfile');
S = strsplit(S, '\n');
if isempty(S{end}); S(end) = []; end   % If there was an empty line, remove it

% Create a struct array, one struct per line
for i = 1 : length(S)
   % process mandatory character and integer
   Out(i).char = S{i}(1);              % get the first character of that line

   IntIndices = regexp( S{i}, '\d' );  % get the integer part as indices
   Out(i).int  = S{i}( IntIndices );   % note: integer returned as string
                                       %       to preserve 0-padding

   % process optional string and hash
   if IntIndices(end) == length(S{i})  % no optional string exists after integer
       Out(i).str = '';
       Out(i).hash = false;
   else
       Out(i).str  = S{i}( IntIndices(end) + 1 : end ); % get remaining string
       if strcmp( Out(i).str(end), '#' ) 
           Out(i).str(end) = [];       % remove the final hash if it exists
           Out(i).hash = true; 
       else
           Out(i).hash = false;
       end 
   end
end
```